# Arduino - Burning Bootloader without External Crystal

Tags: arduino, bootloader

I'm trying to burn the bootloader to an ATMEGA328P - AUR, the 32-pin SMD variation with my Arduino Uno. I've tried the recommended way that the Arduino website suggests to burn the bootloader. However, I don't have the 16MHz crystal recommended, so I tried the workaround method they describe to use the internal 8MHz oscillator. Burning the bootloader gives me the "Yikes! Invalid device signature" error. Do you think there is an incompatibility with the chip? Problem with using the internal oscillator? Should I just get the crystal?

Comment: You will probably get more answers on http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, thanks! I didn't know that was an option.  I'll look there.

Answer (score 1):

---

**For just invalid device signature - (this usually occurs if internal clock is on)**

For the ATMEGA328p if it is preloaded with a bootloader for some reason there is a mismatch in signatures so you'll have to do this THEN UNDO IT << please don't forget or else you'll have to bootload everytime before you write a script until you UNDO this.

1. You'll want to open up the avrdude.conf file in Arduino's program files

   > for mac: show package contents for PC and Linux just search the Program Files
2. in this file search for " ATMEGA328P " under it should be a field named signature replace "0x1e 0x95 0x14" (the 328 signature) with "0x1e 0x95 0x0F" (the 328p signature)
3. Follow step 2 - 4  below, if this works you're all set.

---

**if internal clock is not on a sync error occurs**

The ATMEGA328p has an internal oscillator which operates at 8MHz but this oscillator is apparently turned off when the a 16MHz bootloader is burned to it. So if you are gonna burn an 8MHz (lilypad) type bootloader to it you'll have to do so with the 16MHz oscillator in place so the internal clock can be turned on.

To do this:

1. load ArduinoISP example script on the UNO R3 that you're going to be boot loading with
2. (Configure in Tools > Boards > LilyPad Arduino or ATMEGA328 on breadboard)
3. (Configure in Tools > Port > ArduinoISP)
4. Afterwards you should be ready to burn boot loader

---

**if sync error persist it means that the clocks are missaligned meaning you've got to slow down the boot loader**

1. in the Hardware folder search for a boards.txt file within the avr folder
2. edit the line in the file containing "atmega328bb.upload.speed=57600" to read "atmega328bb.upload.speed=19200"
3. try steps 2 - 4 just above again

Try each of these steps in various combinations or appropriately as the problem evolves. If this doesn't seem to work just continue search forums... I had found all this in about 3 hrs on google - good luck!